# Change column value in pandas df conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas df.

```
id   count
1      1
2      5
3      7
4      9
5      NaN
6      NaN
```

i want to change count to `1` wherever the count is `Nan`

```
df['count'] = 1
```

this would make all the columns to 1 but i dont want that, is there any way to define if condition in pandas df

Comment: you don't need a condition here, `fillna` will just do what you want

Comment: `if not df[count]:df[count] = 1`?

Comment: As @EdChum noted, this is a `fillna` question, just where you pass a value of `1` instead.

Comment: How did this question get two upvotes?